# JasperReports jrxml file not parsed correctly

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The following is my Report.jrxml file. I have an ArrayList of a custom class which has parameters createdOn,actionby etc and I wish to populate the report based on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2015-12-21T18:21:11 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="_blank" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ced95029-b569-4027-895c-af2843a4e088">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="logotwo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#03A9F4" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="12"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Opaque" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="12">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#000000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <field name="filePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="createdOn" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="actionby" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="actionType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="createdOn"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{createdOn}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="37">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="-21" y="7" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="df26104b-a7fc-458f-8a21-50b13c7c7736"/>
                    <rectangle>
                        <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="21" y="0" width="36" height="24" backcolor="#03A9F4" uuid="369745f3-8095-4b8b-8b7a-38e42b7aef67"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </rectangle>
                    <textField pattern="dd-MM-yyyy">
                        <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="10" y="0" width="413" height="24" forecolor="#E50000" uuid="ef0a10c7-2940-4ac1-a69e-db1a00ae6f2e"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{createdOn}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="6"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <image hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="150" y="372" width="200" height="200" uuid="42c96db8-4afd-4834-ba69-6b211df0c42f"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logotwo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="136" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="126" uuid="ddc15723-2728-421f-b95e-2df9faf64ce1"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="170" y="0" width="230" height="60" uuid="1a652692-054a-40f3-ade5-68d8da36626d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="219" y="62" width="196" height="22" uuid="88d4231e-f014-4b0d-b871-1737ba63a1ae"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Activity Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="172" y="94" width="383" height="42" uuid="f0bfb1ea-a85a-47cd-a1a4-43f22b45e80f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="15" width="555" height="1" uuid="1a61a836-d137-48b1-ad67-6ff64600bf93"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="20" y="0" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="8093e6b6-1479-4d7e-a3e1-8b43ac16fe34"/>
                <text><![CDATA[User]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="120" y="0" width="138" height="15" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="c9463f8f-ce24-4798-9f83-1122da0d5f31"/>
                <text><![CDATA[File Path]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="400" y="0" width="138" height="15" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="cfb1f8c6-3240-4393-be47-70b56eea3926"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Action Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Row" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" forecolor="#009688" uuid="a98495d8-3c8d-4fa0-81f5-30c3efc2f766"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="20" y="0" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#009688" uuid="714380ba-f273-4f2c-9a24-e01f345aeb03"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{actionby}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="120" y="0" width="250" height="15" forecolor="#009688" uuid="e7d518fc-f335-40ab-acc1-8858f53a806e"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{filePath}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="400" y="0" width="150" height="15" forecolor="#009688" uuid="34a6eb4a-7c05-4129-815e-ae1153f52798"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{actionType}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="fa45a887-615a-4d84-a2d7-8a2219671b3c"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="-21" y="1" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="183682bc-d976-4756-83e0-6625a3f98ed1"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="533" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="0193f9b3-1559-491a-8580-b6988863b6a1"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="453" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="d00b105e-494b-418b-8ac9-8b1b4824f4f0"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#03A9F4" uuid="0616f3fe-0354-456f-8911-ec30ec51a5ae"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**NOTE** :
I have added the parameters on my own ie logo and logotwo and the parsing errors started when I did so. I have serious doubts whether it is based on them.

Anyways,when I try running my project , I get this error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 78; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'style'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":parameter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":queryString, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":field, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":sortField, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is expected.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:302)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:285)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:274)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:248)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:341)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:608)
    at com.ram.report.ReportGen.execute(ReportGen.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at com.vmr.general.actions.login.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:905)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 78; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'style'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":parameter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":queryString, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":field, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":sortField, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:298)
    ... 83 more
```

When I looked up at the **Markers** tab in Eclipse, I found that there were errors in line 9 and 13 which had similar errors

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'style'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":parameter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":queryString, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":field, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":sortField, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is expected.   Report.jrxml    /vmr/src/com/ram/report/jasper  line 9  JRXML Problem
```

I had actually designed the .jrxml file with JasperStudio Plugin with Eclipse and **edited** the Coffee template to suit my needs.

This is a relevant snippet of my Action class code

```
               try
                {
                    System.out.println("coming to this method");
                    java.io.InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/ram/report/jasper/Report.jrxml");
                    JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(in);
                    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    params.put("logotwo", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("logo2.png").getPath());
                    params.put("logo", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("logo.png").getPath() );
                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
                    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I don't know what is wrong with this. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `style` tag's before `parameter` tag's

es.

```
<style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#03A9F4" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Detail" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="12"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Opaque" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="12">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#000000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<parameter name="logotwo" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

For complete [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd) see [jasperreport.xsd](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd)

Comment: Thanks Petter! :D  Can you tell me where I can learn the order in which I need to give the xml tags? I couldn't find a proper ordering in the places I checked.

Comment: @zorro_blue, I have edit the answer with a link to jasper report xsd.